# Background, занимающий половину длины

Tags: html, css

Как добавить background к элементу, который будет занимать половину контейнера (по длине)? Я могу это сделать с помощью `linear-gradient`:

```css
.half-background {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #69f0ae 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="half-background">test text</div>
```

Но этот способ мне не подходит. Есть ли другой способ?

Comment: А почему не подходит вариант с градиентом?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием псевдоэлементов `(:before, :after)`

```css
.half-background{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.half-background:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #69F0AE;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-background">test text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать изображение размером в 1 пиксель нужного цвета, положить его в background, задав ширину 50%, а еще задать цвет. Цвет зальёт весь блок, а однопиксельное изображение займет только половину. В сниппете однопиксельное изображение черного цвета задано инлайн через base64.

```css
.half-background {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAUEBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=);
  background-size: 50% auto;
  background-color: cyan;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-background">test text</div>
```